# Assign values insde sql statement - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to assign default value inside a sql statement like.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN sd.IID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sd.IID END) AS IID, 
    pd.IID AS PurchaseOrerDetailsId, 
    i.[Description] AS Item, 
    sd.BatchNo, s.[Description] AS Unit,        
    CONVERT(varchar, sd.MfgDt, 103) AS MfgDt,
    sd.Qty = 0,
    CONVERT(varchar, sd.ExpiryDate, 103) AS ExpiryDate,
    sd.PackSize ='',
    pd.Qty = 0 AS QtyOrdered,
    sd.MRP, sd.PTR,
    sd.PurchaseRate,
    sd.PTS,
    sd.CGST,
    sd.SGST,
    sd.IGST,
    DiscPer,
    DiscVal,
    sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate AS PurchaseValue,
   (sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.CGST)/100 AS CGSTAmt,
   (sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.SGST)/100 AS SGSTAmt,
   (sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.IGST)/100 AS IGSTAmt,
    i.IID AS ItemId
FROM PurchaseOrderDetails pd
```

But you can see "Qty = 0" or PackSize ='' inside SELECT statement will not work. How can I assign values inside a SELECT statement for for multiple fields.

Thanks
Partha

Comment: Are you trying to assign values to a table, or just to the results you see in the SSMS query-window results?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: do you just mean 0 as qty instead of sd.qty = 1?  Not sure if you are trying to have a constant be returned here or if you're trying to set a field = 0 using a select statement

Comment: I've edited your SQL to be readable (as it really wasn't), however, I've left some comments in there for you. For example you're mixing of how you alias, and the conversion of a value to `varchar` (without a length).

Comment: If you want your table to have a default value then a constraint is probably a good idea rather than putting a CASE statement in your queries.

Comment: If you want a static value returned, just select the static value. You can't say the column and provide a value. You are saying "give me the value from the column but change it to x". Either get the value from the column OR provide the constant.

Comment: Bearing in mind that a default value will be used to replace a NULL value, you can use the ISNULL method (example: ISNULL(Field,[DefaultValue])) for all your attributes in your query.

Comment: I think that was an edit here.

Comment: @Larnu You've been here long enough than to know better than to respond to OP via an edit. Cleaning up the formatting is fine; the comments needed to be elsewhere.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn and now the OP (probably) has no idea what i'm talking about.

Comment: Then write an answer. Don't munge up answers and questions. That's not how SO operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN sd.IID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sd.IID END) AS IID, 
pd.IID AS PurchaseOrerDetailsId, 
i.[Description] AS Item, 
sd.BatchNo, 
s.[Description] AS Unit, 
CONVERT(varchar, sd.MfgDt, 103) AS MfgDt, 
'0' AS sd.Qty, 
CONVERT(varchar, sd.ExpiryDate, 103) AS ExpiryDate, 
'' AS sd.PackSize, 
pd.Qty = 0 AS QtyOrdered, 
sd.MRP,
sd.PTR, 
sd.PurchaseRate, sd.PTS, sd.CGST, sd.SGST, sd.IGST, DiscPer, DiscVal, sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate AS PurchaseValue, (sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.CGST)/100 AS CGSTAmt, 
(sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.SGST)/100 AS SGSTAmt, (sd.Qty * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.IGST)/100 AS IGSTAmt, i.IID AS ItemId
            FROM PurchaseOrderDetails pd
```

Not sure about QtyOrdered column though

Answer (score 0):

Refering my previous comment...
Why not just with this?

```
ISNULL(Qty,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sd.IID,0) AS IID, 
    pd.IID AS PurchaseOrerDetailsId, i.[Description] AS Item, 
    sd.BatchNo, s.[Description] AS Unit,        
    CONVERT(varchar, sd.MfgDt, 103) AS MfgDt,
    COALESCE(sd.Qty,0) As Qty,
    CONVERT(varchar, sd.ExpiryDate, 103) AS ExpiryDate,
    COALESCE(sd.PackSize,'') As PackSize,
    COALESCE(pd.Qty,0) AS QtyOrdered,
    sd.MRP, sd.PTR, sd.PurchaseRate,
    sd.PTS, sd.CGST, sd.SGST, sd.IGST, 
    DiscPer, DiscVal,
    COALESCE(sd.Qty,0) * sd.PurchaseRate AS PurchaseValue,
   (COALESCE(sd.Qty,0) * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.CGST)/100 AS CGSTAmt,
   (COALESCE(sd.Qty,0) * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.SGST)/100 AS SGSTAmt,
   (COALESCE(sd.Qty,0) * sd.PurchaseRate * sd.IGST)/100 AS IGSTAmt,
    i.IID AS ItemId
FROM PurchaseOrderDetails pd
```